# Running Java Application using Popen

Tags: java, python, linux, apache-tika

I am running tika on my Linux server, and I want to run it using python (subprocess.Popen)

However, I have a non-root access, so I only have a local java installation. Every time I need to set the java home and path for each session :

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin

Then I can run tika from the java directory and save the output to some file `out_txt.txt`

> curl www.vit.org/downloads/doc/tariff.doc   | java -jar
>   tika-app-1.3.jar --text >out_txt.txt

So, I need to know how to use Popen to:

1. set the java home and path using Popen
2. write Tika output to the file `out_txt.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you could:

- use `os.setenv('JAVA_HOME', '/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07')` before `Popen`, that would set the environment variable for all futre invocations. or for `PATH`:

  ```
  os.environ['PATH'] += ":/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07"
  ```
- pass an environment dict to `Popen` as [`env`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess#popen-constructor):

  ```
  environ = os.environ.copy()
  environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07'
  environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin'
  subprocess.Popen(args, env=environ)
  ```

2)

- open the file for writing and pass it to `Popen` as `stdout` (and optionally `stderr`):

  ```
  output = open(outfile, 'wb')
  subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=output, stderr=output)
  ```
- leave it to the shell by passing `shell=True` to `Popen`:

  ```
  Popen("curl www.vit.org/downloads/doc/tariff.doc | java -jar tika-app-1.3.jar --text >out_txt.txt", shell=True)
  ```

Comment: Just great, I only seem to have a problem with the command Popen("curl www.vit.org/downloads/doc/tariff.doc | java -jar tika-app-1.3.jar --text >out_txt.txt", shell=True), because when I set the path to the Java directory, it does not have the "curl" 
I get the following: >>> /bin/sh: curl: command not found
so is there a way to be able to run Java and curl at the same time?

Comment: you shouldn't _replace_ the `PATH`, but append the java bin directory to it. updated my answer to reflect this. or just use full paths.